# function is being called automatically in JS

Tags: javascript, frontend

I was trying to create a parameterized function using JS, I started code with a window.onload=()=>{},
and the syntax for my function is `function name(arg){}`.

I want to call this function on a click event. so my statement goes `btn.onclick=function_name(arg);` . but, the function gets called as soon as the page loads, without a click. What can i do to solve this problem?

```
window.onload = () => {
  var btn .....

  btn.onclick = func(arg..);

  function func(arg){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`btn.onclick = func(arg..);` calls the function and assigns the return value to the onclick property of btn.

Attach an event listener to the button with the snippet code. You can use data- attributes to add data to the button.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", fn);

function fn(e) {
  this.textContent = "Clicked " + this.dataset.arg;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" data-arg="arg">Click</button>
```